# why login page redirect to index page when submit the form in nuxt?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js

I am trying to do a normal login page using nuxt and nuxt/auth module.
i what is hapening is that when click the submit button a riderect to the index page is hapening. 
this is my html code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <b-card
     header="Sign In"
     header-bg-variant="secondary"
     header-text-variant="white"
     style="width: 20rem;"
   >
     <b-form @submit="onSubmit">
      <b-form-group
        id="input-group-1"
        label="Username:"
        label-for="input-1"
      >
       <b-form-input
        id="input-1"
        v-model="form.userName"
        type="email"
        required
        placeholder=""
      ></b-form-input>
       </b-form-group>

       <b-form-group id="input-group-2" label="Password:" label-for="input-2">
         <b-form-input
           id="input-2"
           type="password"
           required
           v-model="form.password"
           placeholder=""
         ></b-form-input>
       </b-form-group>

       <b-form-group id="input-group-3" label="Reference:" label-for="input-3">
        <b-form-input
        id="input-3"
        v-model="form.reference"
        required
        placeholder=""
      ></b-form-input>
      </b-form-group>
      <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
  </b-form>
  </b-card>
 </div>
 </template>
```

and this is my JS submit function:

```
async onSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var self = this;
    var data = {
      email: self.form.userName,
      password: self.form.password,
      role: "publisher"
    };

    try{
      await this.$auth.loginWith("local", {
        data: data
      })
    }catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      self.emailCheck = true;
    }

    if (this.$auth.loggedIn) {
      axios.defaults.headers.common["authorization"] = self.$auth.getToken(
        "local"
      )
      axios.get(self.baseUrl + "devices/config/" + self.form.reference)
        .then(async function (response) {

          self.$router.push({
            name: "mediaPlayer"
          });

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
          self.refCheck = true;
        });
      }
    }
```

i tried to put the prevent event in the html like this `@submit.stop.prevent="onSubmit"` but nothing also.
what i want is to go to the mediapalyer page if the login is done or just do the console of the err if it is not.